# Join between two tables

Tags: sql, join

**table1 - doctors**

```
+---------+--------+------+
| country |  state |  doc |
+---------+--------+------+
| india   |  AP    | 20   |
+---------+--------+------+
| india   |  TN    | 30   |
+---------+--------+------+
| india   |  KA    | 10   |
+---------+--------+------+
| US      |  LA    | 30   |
+---------+--------+------+
| US      |  CA    | 10   |
+---------+--------+------+
| US      |  NY    | 50   |
+---------+--------+------+
```

**table2 - engineers**

```
+---------+--------+-------+
| country |  state |  engg |
+---------+--------+-------+
| india   |  AP    | 100   |
+---------+--------+-------+
| india   |  TN    | 400   |
+---------+--------+-------+
| india   |  KA    | 250   |
+---------+--------+-------+
| US      |  LA    | 140   |
+---------+--------+-------+
| US      |  CA    | 120   |
+---------+--------+-------+
| US      |  NY    | 150   |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

**Desired output:**

```
+---------+------+-------+
| country |  doc |  engg |
+---------+------+-------+
| india   | 60   | 750   |
+---------+------+-------+
| US      | 90   | 410   |
+---------+------+-------+
```

I tried with the below query but am getting more count of docs and engg. Someone please correct me..

```
select country, sum(a.doc), sum(b.engg) 
  from table1 a join table2 b on (a.country = b.country)
```

Comment: Hi kiran, welcome to SO. For better readability, please format your code using the code formatting option. To make tables more readable, you can use a tool like [Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT
    country,
    SUM(doc) AS doc,
    SUM(engg) AS engg
FROM
    (SELECT
        country,
        doc,
        0 AS engg
     FROM
        doctors
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
        country,
        0,
        engg
     FROM
        engineers
    ) a
GROUP BY
    country
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you are getting a cross-product of both the tables with these set of values.

Try using:

```
tableA NATURAL JOIN tableB.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by country.

```
select a.country, sum(docSum), sum(enggSum) from
  (select country, sum(doc) docSum from doctors) a
inner join
  (select country, sum(engg) enggSum from engineers)
on a.country = b.country
group by a.country
```

Comment: this won't return any engineer counts for countries without doctors

Comment: That is correct.  What you stated was not part of the requirements, however.  For all we know this could be explicitly for comparing doctor counts to engineer counts in which null doctor or engineer countrys are irrelevant.